# Spam someone in Instagram: How to input multiple messages in the textbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, instagram

I want to send multiple messages on Instagram through their website. So far I am able to login and open the particular person's dm. I want to select the textbox and send some input. I am trying this code

```py
messageBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='                   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        
vwCYk                                        ItkAi                                                                       
']")
messageBox.click()
messageBox.send_keys("test")
send = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ']")
send.click()
```

It is raising the error that the element (messageBox) is not interactable at the moment.

I also tried putting input using javascript.

```py
messageBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='                   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        
vwCYk                                        ItkAi                                                                       
']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'test';", messageBox)
```

However this doesn't input anything and there is no error raised either.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the input either hidden or capacity is set 0

if the capacity is set 0 try this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver(); 
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"yourSelector\").style.opacity='1'");
```

then try to sendKeys the value

in case of hidden input use this

```
document.querySelector(\"yourSelector\").style.display ='active'
```

then try to sendKeys the value

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but in the end, this worked out.

```py
messageBox = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")
messageBox.click()
messageBox.send_keys("test")
```

Here is the complete code if anyone is wondering

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

username = ""        #your username 
password = ""        #password

time.sleep(2)

#login
usernamefield = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
usernamefield.click()
usernamefield.send_keys(username)

passwordfield = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
passwordfield.click()
passwordfield.send_keys(password)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='                   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                                              ']")
login.click()

time.sleep(5)

popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']")
popup.click()

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/")

time.sleep(2)

#select the first person on your dm list
contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='-qQT3 rOtsg']")
contact.click()

time.sleep(2)

#send messages in succession
message = ""                       #your message
for i in range(500):
    messageBox = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")
    messageBox.click()
    messageBox.send_keys(message)       

    send = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='                   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                        JI_ht                                                                      ']")
    send.click()
```